# CEP para Latitude e Longitude Python

Tags: python

Gostaria de rodar um CSV que contem mais de 100 CEPs e me retornasse, em um outro CSV, Latitude e Longitude.

Já tenho a base para transformar o CEP. Mas não estou conseguindo ler um CSV linha por linha e retornar latitude e longitude.

```
import pycep_correios
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

endereco = pycep_correios.get_address_from_cep('01001010')

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")
location = geolocator.geocode(endereco['logradouro'] + ", " + endereco['cidade'] + " - " + endereco['bairro'])

print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
```

Comment: Você precisa "abrir" o CSV no seu arquivo. Dá uma olhada aqui: [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 5):

Assumindo que seu arquivo `.csv` contém uma lista simples de ceps. Ex:

```
cep
01001010
01017000
```

1. Faça a leitura do arquivo `.csv` utilizando o método `open()` do Python, e armazene os ceps em uma lista:

   ```
   import csv    
   lista_ceps = []   
   with open('ceps.csv') as file:
       next(file)  # Pula o cabeçalho, caso exista
       for row in csv.reader(file):
           lista_ceps.append(row[0])
   ```
2. Transforme o seu código para conversão de cep em uma função:

   ```
   import pycep_correios
   from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

   def extrai_lat_long(cep):
       endereco = pycep_correios.get_address_from_cep(cep)

       geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")
       location = geolocator.geocode(endereco['logradouro'] + ", " + endereco['cidade'] + " - " + endereco['bairro'])

       return(location.latitude, location.longitude)
   ```
3. Crie um novo `.csv` com o CEP, latitude e longitude, usando o mesmo método `open()`, mas dessa vez com o arquivo de saída, e com o parâmetro `'w'` para indicar que a operação é de escrita (*write*):

   ```
    with open('ceps_lat_long.csv', 'w') as file:
        cabecalho = ['cep', 'latitude', 'longitude']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=cabecalho)

        writer.writeheader() # Escreve o cabeçalho
        for cep in lista_ceps:
            latitude, longitude = extrai_lat_long(cep)
            writer.writerow({'cep': cep, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})
   ```

O arquivo `ceps_lat_long.csv` ficará assim:

```
cep,latitude,longitude
01001010,-23.5512564,-46.6338028
01017000,-23.5453334,-46.6206464
```

Espero que tenha ficado claro!